# When should TypeApplications be preferred over simple :: signatures or ScopedTypeVariables?

Tags: haskell, types

Considering this simple example of ambiguous type inference:

```
#! /usr/bin/env stack
{- stack runghc -}

{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- This will fail to compile without additional type info
  -- let w = read "22"
  -- print w
  
  -- My go-to for this is type signatures in the expressions
  let x = read "33" :: Integer
  print x 
  
  -- Another possibility is ScopedtypeVariables
  let y :: Integer = read "44"
  print y
  
  -- How does TypeApplications differ from the code above? When should this be chosen instead?
  let z = read @Integer "55"
  print z
```

My question is, in cases like this, is there an advantage to using `TypeApplications`?

Comment: In this particular case - no, there is no practical difference. The difference is only aesthetic. And this would apply to any case, except those where providing a type signature is actually impossible for some reason.

Comment: In most cases, a type signature can be used, but often it's more verbose.  One of my favorite aesthetic cases for using TypeApplications is with `Proxy`, i.e., replacing `Proxy :: Proxy Int` with `Proxy @Int`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In almost all cases, it is an aesthetic choice only. I make the following additional comments for your consideration:

- In all cases, if a thing typechecks with some collection of type signatures, there is a corresponding collection of type applications that also causes that term to typecheck (and with the same choices of instance dictionaries, etc.).
- In cases where either a signature or an application can be used, the code produced by GHC will be identical.
- Some ambiguous types cannot be resolved via signatures, and type applications must be used. For example, `foo :: (Monoid a, Monoid b) => b` cannot be given a type signature that determines `a`. (This bullet motivates the "almost" in the first sentence of this answer. No other bullet motivates the "almost".)
- Type applications are frequently syntactically lighter than type signatures. For example, when the type is long, or a type variable is mentioned several times. Some comparisons:

  ```
    showsPrec :: Int -> Bool -> String -> String
    showsPrec @Bool

    sortOn :: Ord b => (Int -> b) -> [Int] -> [Int]
    sortOn @Int
  ```

  Sometimes it is possible to shuffle the type signature around to a different subterm so that you need only give a short signature with little repetition. But then again... sometimes not.
- Sometimes, the signature or application is intended to convey some information to the reader or encourage a certain way of thinking about a piece of code (i.e. is not *strictly* for compiler consumption). If part of that information involves attaching the annotation in a specific code location, your options may be somewhat constrained.